# Mount a directory in buffered write mode

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

I have a directory which is write-intensive (`/home/user/project/.comp`, used by the compilation tools), is there a way to buffered the writes only for this directory? (every one hour or at shutdown)
I use ArchLinux with ext4 on a SSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the size of the directory and memory available, you might be able to create a ramdisk of suitable size, then mount it in "project/.comp".

A cron job and a shutdown task could then `rsync` it with the real "project/.comp-real".

You might also want to experiment with different file systems (XFS, for example) on the ramdisk.